# Run expect script in current directory

Tags: linux, shell, expect

I wrote a sftp expect script to upload and download files.

I put the script file in a folder. And double click the script to run the script to log in the remote server, but every time my script will log in the server in home folder not in the folder that where the script is.

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
set login "username"
set addr "server.com"
set pw "mypassword"
set timeout -1
sleep 1
spawn sftp $login@$addr
expect "Password:" {send "$pw\r"}
sleep 1
interact
```

For example, I put this script on /Desktop and if I want to upload some files to my server from /Desktop in my local machine, I still have to cd into /Desktop and than run this script, if I just double click to execute the script it will log into my server from the ~ or /root whatever the default directory is. I want to log in my server from the directory where the script is.

#### Is there any way that I can find the location of a file? Or I need perform a searching to locate the file?

Comment: You'll need to provide your code.

Comment: cant you provide complete/absolute path on server from where to download and upload files instead of using reference locations and increasing dependency?

Comment: But I still need to set up the path if I want to upload file from a different directory, can I do just drag the script to that directory and run the script, the script will find out it's directory and cd in that directory? Do I have to do a searching to find the directory of the script file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want

```
cd [file dirname $argv0]
```

to change into the directory where the script lives.